# Can I still reach my desired IBU level if I split my boil?

Tags: boil, partial-boil

In my recipe I have a boil size of 10L. Can this be split into 2 x 5L pots whereby half the ingredients would be used in each, but still reach the desired IBUs of a single 10L boil?

Fingers crossed, otherwise I need more hops...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you split the wort and hops accurately you'll be so close you'll never notice the difference.